# What is the effect of pesticides on worm growth?

Tags: ecology, environment, research-process, research-design

As a new semester begins, we were asked to propose ideas for investigatory projects. Our idea revolves around the effects of pesticides on non-target organisms. Since frequent use of pesticides may potentially affect the health of the soil, we chose the earthworms as our target organism. Our experimental set-up was revolves around studying their growth. Two containers (Container A-Control, Container B-Experimental) would be filled with soil and other things that are essential for worms to live. In container A, normal soil would be used. On container B, we would spray pesticide on the soil and mix them so that it really gets in the soil. After that, we would place the worms (5 each container). The allotted time for data gathering and analysis is 3 weeks. Given this situation, we would observe the behavior of the worm each day for 10 to 14 days (depending on our schedule) and their growth on the last day by measuring their length, weight, and describing their color.

I think that our set-up is logical instead of finding farms that sprayed pesticide for the last 20 or so years which is difficult in our situation. Does anyone have any feedback on the particulars of the experiment based on previous research on the subject?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question in terms of SE Biology but a request for discussion and opinion. "What do you think?" Is one of the examples of this given in the help on writing questions.

Comment: But @David, this is a perfectly valid question on experimental design by a budding biologist. How does the fact that the OP is asking for the opinion of experts detract from the merit of the question? It is my impression that this is what this site is for. This question can be answered with evidence. There may be a range of things that one could suggest but one can cite reasons why an approach is or is not appropriate, or preferred over others. I, for one, would like to reward questions such as this one that show some genuine interest and effort from the part of the OP.

Comment: I have suggested some edits to make the question more general. Feel free to modify or rollback if you do not approve my changes.

Comment: To @vkehayas (and OP). Please read the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and the Help section on [Questions to Avoid Asking](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and you will see why this question is off-topic for this list as it is constituted. 1. It is not a question about biology, as in the three  examples listed under “Ask about...”. 2. It is not a “questions about an actual problem”. 3. It is “primarily opinion-based... likely to generate discussion rather than answers”. 4. It is a “subjective question” having something in common with three of the examples given.

Comment: @David, unfortunately I cannot see this question violating any of the criteria. Since we've both voiced our opinion I'd suggest we now leave the community decide on this one.

Comment: "Pesticides and earthworms. A review": https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13593-013-0151-z

Comment: @vkehayas If you still cannot see why the question is off topic there is no point in further communication with you. I would ask others to read the links I provided.